# Improve results of a clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to do a clustering of a multi-sentence text, but my results are horrible. Any tips for me to improve my result?

```
import pandas
import pprint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

dataset = pandas.read_csv('text.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

comments = dataset['comments']

comments_list = comments.values.tolist()

vetorize = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vetorize.fit_transform(comments_list)

clusters_number = 6
model = KMeans(n_clusters = clusters_number, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 1)

model.fit(X)

centers = model.cluster_centers_
labels = model.labels_

clusters = {}
for verbatim, label in zip(verbatim_list, labels):
    try:
        clusters[str(label)].append(verbatim)
    except:
        clusters[str(label)] = [verbatim]
pprint.pprint(clusters)

#Top terms for cluster
print("Top termos par cluster:")
ordem_centroides = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
termos = vetorizar.get_feature_names()
for i in range(clusters_number):
    print ("Cluster %d:" % i,)
    for ind in ordem_centroides[i, :10]:
        print (' %s' % termos[ind],)
        print()
```

I have many different themes present in various clusters. I pre-processed my data (stopwords, lowercase, I removed the punct...). But still I have 'like to cancel order' in one cluster and 'love cancel order' in another. When, in fact, the ideal is to join all 'cancel order' in a single cluster.

Comment: why do you say your results are terrible? What is your goal?
Can you show some examples of what your `text.csv` looks like and what kind of information you expect to get from clustering?

Comment: I have many different themes present in various clusters. I pre-processed my data (stopwords, lowercase, I removed the punct...). But still I have 'like to cancel order' in one cluster and 'love cancel order' in another. When, in fact, the ideal is to join all 'cancel order' in a single cluster.

Comment: Ok, why did you choose `6` clusters?
if you choose 6 but there in truth are 2, you will see your results split.
Do you have a predefined number of clusters that you need to find the items that belong to it?

Comment: I would like to be at least 30. But I do not know if it is possible. I think my program is really bad because even with 60 (yes, 60!) clusters, I have errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very obvious tip I would say is that K-means is not the algorithm you use for clustering text data in general. The nature of text data is a bit more complicated than structured data on which K-means is one of basic but still working algorithms (of course it also depends on the way you model the text i.e. how you convert a text dataset to a of numbers). Let me propose two things with one hint:

### Hint

Document Clustering is also referred to as [Topic Modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model). So you really need to have a look at this as I assume you didn't yet (according to using k-means for this problem). Now we see two standard algorithms for topic modeling but I strongly recommend you to see other algorithms as well.

### NMF

Non-negative Matrix Factorization is a well-known decomposition method for non-negative matrices like TF-IDF or other variants of Bag-of-Words. You can simply apply it to your problem [using SKLearn](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html).

### LDA

or **Latent Dirichlet Allocation** (don't get confused by Linear Discriminant Analysis). This is a pretty standard algorithm for topic modeling and [implementations](https://medium.com/mlreview/topic-modeling-with-scikit-learn-e80d33668730) can be found in SKLearn, Gensim, NLTK, Spacy and other NLP/ML libraries.

Hope it helped! Good Luck :)

Comment: Something I forgot: 1) A bit of cleaning works. Use NLTK.word_tokenize for tokenization. It cleans punctuations and stuff. 2) Include n-grams in your analysis

Comment: You should edit your answer to add this information.